# Singular value decomposition of a matrix multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, svd

If you have two matrices A and B such as through singular value decomposition:

AB = PSV

And any invertible matrix T such as

AB = $PS^{1/2}TT^{-1}S^{1/2}V$

Could you prove that B = $T^{-1}S^{1/2}V$

This question might be too out of context, so to situate it here is the page where I encontered the problem, it is from the book Biological Learning and Control by Sandro Mussa Ivaldi:

[page 264](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73eQ8.png)

Comment: You **can't** "prove" it- that is just one possible value of the many different A and B whose product will give that result.

Comment: I am not sure to get your meaning. If A and (PS^1/2) are invertible... you could prove it by taking T to be T = (P * S^1/2)^-1 * A.. but then you would need to prove that T is also invertible.. no ?

Comment: so you want to prove: there exists an invertible matrix $T$ such that $B=T^{-1}S^{1/2}V$?

Comment: What i ultimately wanted to understand is Pr. Ivaldi reasoning in his book (see pic) ... but hmm I am probably missing something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rank of $AB$ is less than or equal to the minimum of the rank of $A$ and $B$ (this is known as Sylvester's theorem I think). And the rank of $S^{1/2}$ is the same as the rank of $AB$ (SVD theory: rank of $AB$ equals the number of nonzero singular values). The equation $B=T^{-1}S^{1/2}V$ basically states that $B$ and $S^{1/2}$ are equivalent ([matrix equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_equivalence)) and hence must have the same rank. But since the rank of $AB$ may very well be less than the rank of $B$ we see that this cannot be true in general. A trivial counter example: let $A=0$ and $B=I$.